# Why isn't Passenger respecting my custom log format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I need to change the log format of my rails app.

I put [this file](https://github.com/topfunky/hodel_3000_compliant_logger/blob/9b09c9288dd3af7d00c4b652871d34a8b0811b34/lib/hodel_3000_compliant_logger.rb) in lib directory and required it in development.rb env file.

```
require 'hodel_3000_compliant_logger'  
config.logger = Hodel3000CompliantLogger.new(config.log_path)
```

and I should get the output of the development.log file as follows:

```
Jun 28 03:05:13 millisami-notebook rails[18243]: Memory usage: 86888 |
PID: 18243
```

I get this exact log when I start my app with script/server (Mongrel).
But when I run the app via Passenger, the format being logged is Rails' default.

Why doesn't Passenger write to the log file like Mongrel does?

Answer (score 0):

Because Passenger runs your Rails app in production mode, and you've only configured the logger in development mode. Copy your configuration over to the production.rb environment file.

Comment: Thats not the case.
I'm running this in my local Ubuntu and I've setup the RailsEnv to development in vhost and its for sure running in development mode.